# Magento 1.7.1 shipping method

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-methods

I am not sure what is wrong with my shipping method, Every order above 500 getting shipping price 0.Even it blocking other shipping method and make the shipping price to 0. Before I add a price rule if product above 500 free shipping but now I have deleted that, But still I am getting the same, I am not sure how to fix this issue

Comment: can you check table rate??

Comment: flush your magento cache and check it again

Comment: I have tried with cache clear , reindex and removed other two shipping method and tried with all the possibilities. But still shipping getting zero if the product above 500 . 

And regarding Table rate , Do you want me the remove the table rate shipping method ?

Comment: Let be more clear in this , Current i am setting up new product based shipping method and the extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-and-product-shipping.html

The issue which now i am facing is product price  below 500 showing the product based shipping price in checkout page , if i add the shipping cost (in admin >catalog > Mange product) for the product above 500  it automatically showing shipping prices as in checkout page.

Comment: @lisageni did you found solution for this ?

Comment: Yes this was fixed @user9999

Comment: okay ,glad to hear that.